# C++11 thread detach not working

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I understand that when a new thread is spawned it must be joined or detached else terminate shall be called, i have the below piece of code which work fine if i join them, but crashes if i call detach instead, I am not able to understand what's going on under the hood.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
#include "iterator"
#include "string"
#include "memory"
using namespace std;

void func() {
    cout << " func ";
}

int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
    std::vector< std::thread> m_vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
        m_vec.push_back( std::thread(func));
        m_vec[i].detach();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just detaching a thread doesn't give it permission to outlive the main thread. Once the main thread exits, that's the ballgame; the heap is destroyed, things like `cout` are cleaned up. Any remaining threads stand a distinct chance of crashing if they do anything before the process as a whole terminates.

If you `detach` a thread, be prepared to provide your own mechanism for ensuring it does not outlive the main thread.